# Insert data from Table1 to Table2 if not exists, else update data in table2 to match Table1. in either case, delete from Table1

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have two tables (T1 and T2) in SQL server and need to achieve the following goal.

assume columns of T1 are Item_ID, Units
and columns of T2 are Item_ID, Units

for each record in T1 where units > 5, if the record does not exist in T2, insert it to T2 and delete it from T1

for each record in T1 where units > 5, if the record does  exist in T2, update it in T2 and delete it from T1

I tried using merge but it is not working for me, probably im not able to get done in the right way.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Hint:  `MERGE` can do both updates and inserts.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, what would be the query based on my example? sorry but I'm a beginner to SQL and can't get it done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to do updates and inserts on **Table2**;

```sql
merge table2 as target
using table1 as source
on target.ID = source.ID

when not matched by target and source.Units>5
then    
    insert (ID,Units) values (source.ID,source.Units)
when matched and source.Units>5
then
    Update set Units = source.Units

OUTPUT $action,
inserted.ID AS InsertedID,
inserted.Units AS InsertedUnits;
```

Then you need to swap **source** and **target** tables and delete specified rows;

```sql
merge table1 as target
using table2 as source
on target.ID = source.ID

when matched and source.Units>5
then
    delete

OUTPUT $action,
deleted.ID AS DeletedID,
deleted.Units AS DeletedUnits;
```

Comment: Thank you, it helped and resolved the issue